# Approach and Considerations for Diurnal Preferences Study with Segmented Regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, segmented-regression

I have a general question related to the steps I'm taking with segmented regression in R. I'm relatively new to both R and segmented regression, so please forgive me if this question seems rather basic.

My study focuses on diurnal preferences across the lifespan and aims to investigate sex-specific trajectories. I have reason to believe that there may be breakpoints in the relationship, and these breakpoints could differ between men and women. This is why I intend to perform segmented regressions for each sex.

However, before delving into sex-specific analyses, I'm taking a preliminary step to obtain breakpoints that are grounded in the data. These breakpoints will serve as reference points for subsequent segmented analyses by sex. I achieve this by conducting a segmented regression with the entire sample. The breakpoints I derive from this initial analysis will be utilized in the subsequent sex-specific analyses.

My question is whether this approach is methodologically sound. Additionally, I'm curious about the potential for different results in terms of slope values between the analysis of the general sample and the analyses for each sex. How should I reconcile any discrepancies?

Furthermore, when the AIC suggests that a model with the same slopes for both sexes might be a better fit, is it still worthwhile to proceed with separate analyses by sex? Or is this redundant, given the initial analysis with the overall sample?

Thank you in advance for your help.